# AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior - bottom of view off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

When using an `AppBarLayout` with the standard `ScrollingViewBehavior`, the AppBarLayout's sibling will by default be the height of the CoordinatorLayout and the sibling's bottom will be offscreen by the height of the AppBarLayout.

In my use case, the `NestedScrollView` is merely a vehicle to allow for the collapsing of the toolbar, while displaying another scrollable view (fragment in this case) beneath the collapsible toolbar.  The fragment is the one who contains the bottom-pinned view (FAB in this case)

Pictures below demonstrate the issue I am describing, and the code supplied is the basic XML which causes the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Fab Offscreen]
[image: Wrong Height, Expanded]
[image: Wrong Height, Collapsed]

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found to this issue involves 2 parts.

1. Add padding equal to the height of the `AppBarLayout` to the BOTTOM of the `NestedScrollView`.  In my case because the AppBarLayout only contained a `Toolbar`, the height was `?attr/actionBarSize`.
   `android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"`
2. Adding a custom `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener` to the `AppBarLayout` which changes the height of the `NestedScrollView` as the toolbar is collapsed.

   ```
   class ScrollingOffsetFixListener(
       private val nestedScrollView: NestedScrollView
   ): AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

   private var originalHeight = 0
   private var firstOffset = true

   override fun onOffsetChanged(layout: AppBarLayout?, offset: Int) {
       if(firstOffset) {
           firstOffset = false
           originalHeight = nestedScrollView.measuredHeight
       }

       val params = nestedScrollView.layoutParams
       params.height = originalHeight + (offset * -1)

       nestedScrollView.layoutParams = params
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer your own question, this really helped me. I have a different circumstance where the fragment in say your TAB2 did not want to be scrolled, so I used appBarLayout.setExpanded() on tab change to hide the top toolbar which restored the fragment size to the correct height - different approach but with the same result. Thanks again, this one had me confounded for a couple of days - messing with my layouts trying to work out why the bottom kept falling out ;)